# When trying to mkdir() in a directory with 777 permissions I get permission denied

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, apache2, mkdir

When running

```
$id = mysqli_num_rows($resultSelect) + 1;
    $uploadDir = "/projects/$id/";
    mkdir($uploadDir,0777,true);
```

I get the errors

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir0]: Permission denied in /var/www/devx.online/html/php/newProject.php on line 9
```

The directory is owned by www-data and the group is www-data. The permissions is 777 for testing, and even still permissions are denied. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Apache2.

Comment: Please run this command to give permission to directory:
 sudo chmod -R 0777 uploads

Comment: @PHPGeek I have given 777 to all directory from /var/www to /projects, also all owned by www-data.

Comment: Are you sure you have a `/projects` folder right at the filesystem root with world-writeable permissions?

Comment: @mario That is exactly it, thank you. Ctrl+H'd without really thinking.

Answer (score 0):

=> Run this command and You shouldn't need to set the permissions to 777 because it's given to access.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/webserver/www
```

Next enabled all members of the www-data group to read and write files

```
chmod -R g+rw /path/to/webserver/www
```

Hoped it work.

Answer (score 0):

I had incorrect directory structure. It should have been `$uploadDir = "../projects/$id/"` instead of `$uploadDir = "/project/$id/"`. Thank you mario.